# int object is not subscriptable while indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int

i just wanted to make a simple code to find out the strings having the maximum number of similar elements but i got the error int object is not subscriptable while comparing the individual elements of the string with the target string. edit:the error is in the line: if a[b]==t[b]: please help . here in the code i have taken a list of strings and then compared it with the target string alphabet to alphabet and the string having the most number of similar alphabet (with the same index no.) is printed

```
n=int(input('enter the number of elements in the list'))
t=input('enter the target string')
l=[]
for x in range(0,n):
    st=input('enter the string')
    l.append (st)
length=len(t)
high=0
for a in l:
    score=0
    for b in range(0,length):
        if a[b]==t[b]:
            score+=1
    if score>high:
        high=score
        word=a
print('the word with the maximum score is :',word)
```

Comment: `a` isn't a list, it's a value. `a[b]` doesn't work, should probably be just `a`

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error, like what line it is on? And what is your goal, and what have you tried? See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you remove the UPPERCASE please?

Comment: did he change the code at some point i could hvae sworn he appended x

Comment: You can ***beautify*** your article/answer/questions by learning some markdown syntax. You might find out [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io) is somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your appending integeres to l

```
for x in range(0,n):
    st=input('enter the string')
    l.append (x) #here
```

and the you loop l

```
for a in l:
    score=0
    for b in range(0,length):
        if a[b]==t[b]:  <--------- #here you say the b'th value of the integer a
```

an integer is not an array, it only have one value